# Image background-position in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, position, background-image

I am currently going through a website's banner via chrome developer tools(Inspect). I noticed that a particular banner has the following ruleset in its CSS:

```
 banner{ 
     background-position:bottom;
     background-position-x: center;
     background-position-y: center;
  }
```

Is this just a formality?. Because, when I removed the three background properties and set `background-position: center`, the banner wasn't affected in any way.

From a developer wannabe. Thanks

Comment: The first `background-position: bottom` gets overwritten by the following ones.

Answer (score 1):

That banner just has bad CSS.
`background-position` is a shorthand for, `background-position-x` and `background-position-y`.

So,

```css
banner { 
  background-position: bottom;
  background-position-x: center; /* This is not doing anything, because x became 'center' when it was omitted above. */
  background-position-y: center; /* This will override the previously set 'bottom' */
}
```

As you mentioned, `background-position: center` does the same job, since both x and y will be 'center'.

There's nothing wrong with using keywords, but if you're just starting with CSS, I strongly recommend you to get used to using percentages.
(You'll thank me later when you need more specific positioning using `calc()`.

`background: 0% 100%` = `background: left bottom`
`background: 100% 0%` = `background: right top`
`background: 50% 50%` = `background: center center`

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position